# Gesture OnFling not called in ListView

Tags: android, listview, gesture

I need some help with handling the gestures on a listview. 
I have an videoview that I want to be able to detect left and right swipes on the layout below:

[Link to a drawing of the current gesture and what is expected](http://s8.postimg.org/y9p1lrpud/Screen_Shot_2013_11_25_at_5_56_08_PM.png)

The onFling method that i used to capture the event is not called

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private FeedAdapter callback;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context, FeedAdapter callback) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    this.callback = callback; 
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 30;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.v("Tom", "tap");
        triggerTouch();
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        Log.v("Swipe","is called"); // this is not called when swipe is not perfectly straight
        try {
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
                if (diffX > 0) {
                    onSwipeRight();
                } else {
                    onSwipeLeft();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void triggerTouch() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}
}
```

So how to make the onFling be called when user swipes slightly off horizontal?

Thank you for your help!

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change your code below:Be sure to call the superclass implementation

```
  @Override
 public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
     this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

}

hope to help you.

Comment: That won't work because theres no super.onTouchEvent. I believe you meant 
    return super.onTouch(view,motionEvent); 
but that also doesn't work becuz onTouchLisetener's onTouch is abstract

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Answer (score 0):

So, just add this if event.getAction is MotionEvent.Action_move to stop the listview scrolling

```
 // Cancel listview's touch
MotionEvent cancelEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(motionEvent);
cancelEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL |
(motionEvent.getActionIndex() << MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT));
mView.onTouchEvent(cancelEvent);
cancelEvent.recycle();
```